# win_copy module suits to copy installer from controller to windows machine?

Tags: ansible

Can I use **win_copy** module to copy installer from controller machine to windows machine recursively across the network?

A task is to copy the installer and install it in all windows server across the environment using Ansible

```
win_copy: Linux machine to windows machine
    src: /opt/installer/win/xx.ex
    dest: C:\ansible
    remote_src: yes
```

Post copying, install the executable on all win servers? Am I using right approach/technique here?

Comment: ansible is used for that only

Comment: is your issue resolved ? as per the comments in answer ansible controller can be only *nix. Also please avoid sending the playbook/code in comment as the visibility is not good. always update the question

Comment: Solved the problem, Sure will post the code in Question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in you example.

Arg: `remote_src: yes` - If yes, it will go to the remote/target machine for the src.

Result: you copy xx.ex from windows to windows, but on the windows filesystem not path `/opt/installer/win/xx.ex`

If we are talking about moving a file from windows to another windows on different servers via ansible, than most likely no.
If you need transfer file from ansible-server (*nix) to windows, just use win_copy without `remote_src: yes`

Comment: thank you, Am copying from Controller to nodes ( Centos to Windows)

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: start of the windows update
  hosts: win
  serial: 1
  connection: winrm
  become_method: runas
  become_user: sena
  vars:
        ansible_become_password: "*!,W:t?5qc%{~9/"
        file_name : "WindowsSensor_392D4CEC720244B9B1D5434A7AC78AA3-70.exe"
        repo_unix_path : "/home/ansible/"
        win_path : "C:\\Ansible_Installer\\"

- name: Copy installer from Linux to windows
    win_copy:
       src: "{{repo_unix_path}}{{file_name}}"
       dest: "{{win_path}}"

  - name:
    win_package:
       path: "{{win_path}}{{file_name}}"
       productid: auto
       creates_service: "CSFalconService" #if available doesn`t install
       arguments: /install /passive /norestart
```